# Postgresql, inner join or subquery or view?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
user
car
dealer
user_metrics
  - user_id (FK) (required)
  - dealer_id (FK) (can be null)
  - car_id (FK) (can be null)
  - saved
  - .... other columns
```

A user can save a `car` or a `dealership`, when that happens the `user_metrics.saved` is set to true and the related `car_id` or `dealership_id` is set (car_id and dealership_id are exclusive, only one is set for a row).

I want user `A` to be able to see all users that have saved the same cars / dealerships.

So, if user `A` has saved car 1, 2,3 and dealership 5,7, I want to get all users that have saved any of those cars / dealerships.

I thought about inner join on user_metrics, but, I am not sure how to write the entire query that would deliver on this.

What query would allow me to get all users that have saved any of the cars/dealerships a certain user has saved?

Comment: `(PK) (can be null)` You have **three PKs** (which is impossible). Plus: PKs **cannot** be NULL.

Comment: I corrected the typo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand as well maybe the below query solve your problem.

First should find a list of user `A` has been reserved after that should search which of **car** or **dealer** used by another user

```sql
with user_saved_data as (
    select um.*,
           u.name,
           ...
    from user_metrics um
             inner join user u
    on um.user_id = u.id
    where um.saved = true
      and u.id = $1 -- User id of user 'A' or any username (Or use other column for create custom condition)
)
select usd.name as current_reserved_user,
       u.name   as reserved_by_user,
       d.*,
       c.*
from user_metrics um
         inner join user u on um.user_id = u.id
         left join user_saved_data usd on usd.dealer_id notnull and usd.dealer_id = um.dealer_id
         left join user_saved_data usd on usd.car_id notnull and usd.car_id = um.car_id
         left join dealer d on um.dealer_id = d.id
         left join car c on um.car_id = c.id
```

Comment: yes, I think approach could work. I'll try to write my query following this model and test things out. Thanks

Comment: using the `with` (CTE approach) is working great for me. Thanks.